# How do I get the URL of a specific size featured image?

Tags: templates, post-thumbnails, images

I am using `<?php wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment_id ); ?>` to get the url of a thumbnail for a post in Wordpress. However I would like to retrieve the URL of a specific size image. So for example when displaying the post thunmbnail normally you can specify a size, like: `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>`. Is it possible to do the same with wp_get_attachment_thumb_url.

Something like: `<?php wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment_id, $size ); ?>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src):

```
if ( $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ) ) {
    echo $src[0]; // URL
    echo $src[1]; // Width
    echo $src[2]; // Height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to retrieve the URL for a different size of the featured image (post thumbnail). In this example I’m echoing out the “large” size:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large')[0]; ?>
```

Works both inside and outside of the loop. (I use this to fill out meta tags in the head for itemprop, Open Graph, etc.)

The [0] at the end is necessary because wp_get_attachment_image_src returns an array, with the first value being the URL.